# Expiration Policy Job - debugging

Tags: timer-jobs, debugging

I am trying to find out what error is preventing our Expiration Policy timer job from completing.

It is scheduled daily about 10PM. Sometimes when I come in in the morning it is Aborted, sometimes it is still on Initialised.

I haven't seen anything in the Windows Event Log and searched the ULS Logs - I can see the event for starting the job, but no messages thereafter.

I believe there may be a large list with an information management policy preventing this job from completing.

Any suggestions or ways to identify the error are appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I think there are 2 jobs. One which evaluates the policy and sets the expiry date and another one that actually expires the document. Do you know which job it is? Also can you make sure their timings are not conflicting with each other?

Comment: @AshishPatel - yep it is the "Expiration Policy" timer job - the one which purges records.  The "Information Management Policy" job completes successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the event logs for errors - after a week I noticed it started working again.  I think it was taking too long, once it caught up it completed successfully again.